# Javascript function not working properly after page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, console.log

So i am trying to change the background of 3 sliders (in this page: https://www.cuscoperu.com/es/testjs) after the page has loaded, i tried this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    function ChangeSliderBck(num, image){
        var urlimg = jQuery('li#Slider-home-' + num).find('div.tp-bgimg.defaultimg').css('background-image');
        console.log("url " + num +  " before: " + urlimg);
        jQuery('li#Slider-home-' + num).find('div.tp-bgimg.defaultimg').css('background-image','url('+ image +')');
        urlimg = jQuery('li#Slider-home-' + num).find('div.tp-bgimg.defaultimg').css('background-image');
        console.log("url " + num +  " after: " + urlimg);
    }
    function ChangeSliders(){
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("es/testjs") > -1){
            var windowsize = jQuery(window).width();
            if(windowsize >= 768){
                ChangeSliderBck(1, "https://www.cuscoperu.com/images/sliders-cuscoperu/slider-Machu-Picchu.jpg");
                ChangeSliderBck(2, "https://www.cuscoperu.com/images/sliders-cuscoperu/slider-huayna-picchu.jpg");
                ChangeSliderBck(3, "https://www.cuscoperu.com/images/sliders-cuscoperu/slider-caminata.jpg");
            }
        }
    }
    ChangeSliders();
});
```

I expected something like this as the console output to confirm that the URLs have been replaced:

```
url 1 before: url("https://www.cuscoperu.com/images/sliders-cuscoperu/slidercellphone/slider-Machu-Picchu-movil.jpg")
url 1 after: url("https://www.cuscoperu.com/images/sliders-cuscoperu/slider-Machu-Picchu.jpg")
```

but the css background-image urls don't actually change and all i get in the console is:

```
url 1 before: undefined
url 1 after: undefined
url 2 before: undefined
url 2 after: undefined
url 3 before: undefined
url 3 after: undefined
```

Any help with this, i am kind of new to javascript and i am not sure what i might be doing wrong, i have executed this code directly in the browser's console and it works correctly, any idea or help is always welcome, thanks.

Comment: If you look at the `length` of the result set returned by `jQuery('li#Slider-home-' + num).find('div.tp-bgimg.defaultimg')` in your `ChangeSliders` function you can see, that it will be `0`. So the elements you are looking for are not in the DOM when you call `ChangeSliders`.

Comment: yeah, your are right, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can use CSS media queries to set background images, no need for JS for this.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

2) Your "REVOLUTION SLIDER" gets created later than your executing script (and hence the nested `div.tp-bgimg.defaultimg` you are searching for. Per initial page load, the `#Slider-home-1` li only contains an `<img>`. So, solution would be to run your script AFTER the initialisation of said slider and the elements are created.